# Show that $(x,y,z)$ is a primitive Pythagorean triple then either $x$ or $y$ is divisible by $3$.

Tags: number-theory, pythagorean-triples

Show that $(x,y,z)$ is a primitive Pythagorean triple then either $x$ or $y$ is divisible by $3$.

The solution is given by 13.1.2: [image]

But how do you become the 2 congruences?

Comment: As for any integer $a\equiv0,1,2\pmod3, a^2\equiv?$

Comment: $a^2$ is always $0$ (mod 3) or $1$ (mod 3) but that does not solve my question...

Comment: You know that congruences can be added, I suppose. So if $x^2\equiv 1\pmod 3$ and $y^2\equiv 1\pmod 3$ then $x^2+y^2\equiv 1+1=2\pmod 3$.

Comment: @user8734617 But how do i know for sure that $x^2=1 (mod 3)$ it can also be 0

Comment: But if $x^2\equiv 0\pmod 3$, this means $3\mid x^2$, but then $3\mid x$ ($3$-prime), and the proof is done in that case. Similarly, if $y^2\equiv 0\pmod 3$ then $3\mid y$.

Comment: $x^2$ cannot be 2 (mod 3) because ... again, congruences can be *multiplied* too, so $x \equiv 0,1,2\pmod 3$ implies $x^2\equiv 0,1,4\equiv 1\pmod 3$, so the remainders of $x^2$ are always just 0 and 1 - never 2.

Answer (score 1):

Primitive Pythagorean triples are generally of two forms:

Form A: $(4i)^2 +(4i^2-1)^2=(4i^2+1)^2; i ∈ N $

$a=4,8,12,...4i$

$b=3,15,35,..4i^2-1$

$c=5,17,37,...4i^2+1$

Form B: $(2i+1)^2+[2i(i+1)]^2=[2i(i+1)+1]^2$

$a=3,5,7,...2i+1$

$b=4,12,24,...2i(i+1)$

$c=5,13,25,...2i(i+1)+1$

By arguing on $i$, it is not difficult to see that for any $i ∈ N$ there is always a number in triple which is a multiple of $3$ or $5$ or$ 3 and 5$:

Form A:

if $i=3k$, then $a=3k$

if $i=3k ± 1$, then $b=4(3k ± 1)^2-1=3p$

if $i=3k ± 2$, then $b=4(3k ± 2)^2-1=3p$

Form B:

if $i=3k $, then $b=2(3k)(3k+1)=3p$

if $i=3k+1$, then $a=2(3k+1)+1=3p$

if $i=3k+2$, then $b=2(3k+2)(3k+3)=3p$

The same argument can be used for $5$.

Comment: [+1] but in fact, as most (rather...) elementary questions, a rapid googling brings the same question 'https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1523230).